# Prove $f^T(x)(\nabla^T f(x)+\nabla f(x))f(x)+x\cdot f(x) = 0$ if and only if $x=0$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

**Properties**

Given a $f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^n$. The function $f$ has the following properties

- $f(x) = 0 $ if and only if $x=0$.
- $\nabla f(x)$ are negative semidefine for any $x$.
- $f(x)$ is continuously differentiable

**Problem**

Is the following iif statement hold?
$$f^T(x)(\nabla^T f(x)+\nabla f(x))f(x)+x\cdot f(x) = 0 \Leftrightarrow x=0.$$
From right to left, it is straightforward. I am trying to prove the left to right.

**Some tries**

According to the negative semidefinite of $\nabla f(x)$, we have $\nabla^T f(x)+\nabla f(x)$ are also negative semidefinite, such that
the first part
$$f^T(x)(\nabla^T f(x)+\nabla f(x))f(x) \leq 0 .$$
Again using $\nabla f(x)$ are negative semidefine, by

**lemma**: If a mapping $f$ is continuously differentiable then $f$ is monotone if and only if its Jacobian matrix $\nabla f(x)$ is positive semidefinite

, we have the second part
$$x\cdot f(x)\leq0.$$

So far, we have
$$f^T(x)(\nabla^T f(x)+\nabla f(x))f(x)+x\cdot f(x) \leq 0.$$
This is the best I can do, I don't know where to go. Or maybe the iif statement is not true in the first place.

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles.

Comment: I would try to factor out $f(x)$ on the left and see if I can tell whether the other factor is ever $0$.

Comment: Indeed you can reduce the expression to $2f(x)^T(∇f(x))f(x)+\int_0^1x^T(∇f(sx))x\,ds$. I see nothing that could prevent $x$ and $f(x)$ to be in the common kernel of $∇f(sx)$, giving the value zero for non-zero $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After an embarrassingly long time, I can now give my own proof of this problem. I will prove the result by contradiction.

Step 1: Let a point $x_3 \neq 0$, which can satisfy the statement $$f^T(x_3)(\nabla^T f(x_3)+\nabla f(x_3))f(x_3)+x_3\cdot f(x_3) = 0 .$$
And also since $x_3\neq0$, $f(x_3) \neq 0$ by property 1.

Step 2: Rewrite the statement as
$$x_3\cdot f(x_3) = -f^T(x_3)(\nabla^T f(x_3)+\nabla f(x_3))f(x_3).$$
Since $\nabla^T f(x_3)+\nabla f(x_3)$ is a negative semidefinite matrix, then $-(\nabla^T f(x_3)+\nabla f(x_3))$ is a positive semidefinite matrix, we have
$$x_3\cdot f(x_3) = -f^T(x_3)(\nabla^T f(x_3)+\nabla f(x_3))f(x_3)\geq 0$$
$$x_3\cdot f(x_3) \geq 0$$

Step 3: By the assumption $x_3$ and $f(x)$ are both not $0$, then
$$x_3\cdot f(x_3) > 0$$

Step 4: By $\nabla f(x_3)$ being negative semidefinite, and using the lemma described above, we should have
$$x_3\cdot f(x_3) \leq 0.$$
This is contradicting with the results of Step 3. That is, the point $x_3 \neq 0$ satisfying the statement would not exist.

Comment: 1) I think we're missing a set of parentheses in step 2: $-(\nabla^\top f(x_3)+\nabla f(x_3))$.
2) Could you flesh out why $f(x)$ is monotone? This does not clearly follow from the answer of the linked problem.

Otherwise, I'd be on-board with this argument!

Comment: Hi @Zim, thanks for your comment. 1) Yes, you are right the parentheses are missing. 2) I am sorry that I wasn't read the link carefully enough that the link could be misleading. I have introduced a lemma in the question part.

Comment: Okay, so the lemma implies that $-f$ is monotone which gives your inequality. Thanks!